# Post data to and from popup window in Asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, popupwindow

```
 //My action
public ActionResult A()
        {return view();}



 //My Main view
       @model   mvcapp.Models.myViewModel

       ViewBag.Title = "A";
        @using (Html.BeginForm("A", "controllerName", new { id="form1"}))
        {
        @Html.DropDownList("dropdwn1", "--Please Select--")
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data)


            <table id="tbl1">
            </table>  
        <input type="button" id="btnAppendRow" value="Add" /> 

        }





 $("#btnAppendRow").click(function () {
$('#tbl1').append(<tr><td><input type="text" value="123"/></td></tr>);
    });


    [Httppost]
public ActionResult A()
{return view();}
```

1).I want to post all the form data (1-dropdown 2-textbox value 3-textbox with value) on a popup window?
and then want to
2). Get back all data on Main view.?

currently when i submit the form the data is displayed to some other page but i want this data on a popup window.

Comment: is there anyone to answer???

Comment: plz share it to anyone who can answer it...